# X509 guide/tutorial in C#

Tags: c#, .net, security, x509certificate

Can anyone point me to a good introductory materials on X509 certificates with examples in C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can begin here

[X509Certificate MSDN Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.aspx)

The System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespace contains the common language runtime implementation of the Authenticode X.509 v.3 certificate. This certificate is signed with a private key that uniquely and positively identifies the holder of the certificate.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that already, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: What are you looking for mainly? why are you looking at X509? Maybe I can help you if you can shed more information.

Answer (score 5):

I found this [C# example](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c.aspx) pretty helpful in figuring out how to generate new certificates.

Also this blog post covering the [more general concepts](http://www.reliablesoftware.com/DasBlog/PermaLink,guid,c953fbc9-34f2-48d4-ba33-55d621a48d7f.aspx)

Other than that you'll need the platform SDK installed, which does also include several other examples (most in C++, but a couple in C# and VB too).

Answer (score 2):

I found this particularly helpful:

[Nine simple steps to enable X.509 certificates on WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/9-simple-steps-to-enable-X-509-certificates-on-WCF)

Also, if anyone's having trouble installing the windows devlopment sdk (to get MakeCert.exe), untick the c++ options in the installer and it seems to work fine.